# Order in which indicies are created affect which index the query optimizer will choose?

Tags: mysql

If I create the following two indicies

```
ALTER TABLE requests ADD INDEX daily_ips(exec_date, ip_address);
ALTER TABLE requests ADD INDEX is_cached(exec_date, cached);
```

The output of `show index from requests` is the following

```
Table       Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
requests    1           daily_ips   1               exec_date   A           413         NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
requests    1           daily_ips   2               ip_address  A           218334      NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
requests    1           is_cached   1               exec_date   A           165         NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
requests    1           is_cached   2               cached      A           165         NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
```

I have the following query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT exec_date,
    100 * SUM(CASE WHEN cached = 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  / SUM(1) cached_no,
    100 * SUM(CASE WHEN cached != 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  / SUM(1) cached_yes
FROM requests
GROUP BY exec_date;

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key         key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  requests    index   NULL            daily_ips   263 NULL    436695
```

However I would like to force the query optimizer to use the `is_cached` index instead of `daily_ips` index.

If I remove the `daily_ips` index and add it again

```
ALTER TABLE requests DROP INDEX daily_ips;
ALTER TABLE requests ADD INDEX daily_ips(exec_date, ip_address);
```

Then run the same `EXPLAIN` statement, the query optimizer chooses the `is_cached` index.

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  requests    index   NULL    is_cached   6   NULL    440493  Using index
```

Is it expected behavior for the query optimizer to choose an index based on the order it was added?

How do I tell the query optimizer which index to use?

Comment: I believe the index is only being used to do a table scan.  If you wanted to actually use the index, you should restructure the query into two queries that do a count with a where condition on on cached.  (Though cached would have to be the first key in the index of course.)  Basically, the CASE is causing you to do a table scan.

Comment: I had updated my answer check that

Comment: @Corbin I'm not sure I understand how I would go about making the query you recommend.  How exactly can I restructure the query into 2 queries (any sample code would be much appreciated)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify that which index sholud be used by query to run.

Try this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT exec_date,
    100 * SUM(CASE WHEN cached = 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  / SUM(1) cached_no,
    100 * SUM(CASE WHEN cached != 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  / SUM(1) cached_yes
FROM requests USE INDEX(is_cached)
GROUP BY exec_date;
```

Differnce between `USE INDEX` and `FORCE INDEX`:

By specifying USE INDEX (index_list), you can tell MySQL to use only one of the named indexes to find rows in the table. The alternative syntax IGNORE INDEX (index_list) can be used to tell MySQL to not use some particular index or indexes. These hints are useful if EXPLAIN shows that MySQL is using the wrong index from the list of possible indexes.

You can also use FORCE INDEX, which acts like USE INDEX (index_list) but with the addition that a table scan is assumed to be very expensive. In other words, a table scan is used only if there is no way to use one of the given indexes to find rows in the table.

**UPDATE**

Try this Query:

```
SELECT exec_date, 
       100 * SUM(IF(cached = 0, 1, 0)) / SUM(1) cached_no, 
       100 * SUM(IF(cached = 1, 1, 0)) / SUM(1) cached_yes 
FROM (SELECT exec_date, IF(cached = 'no', 0, 1) cached 
      FROM requests GROUP BY exec_date) AS A
```

Comment: Thanks! Any difference between `USE INDEX` and `FORCE INDEX`?

Comment: If you satisfied with the answer than accept the answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

To force one index over anothe you may use `FORCE INDEX` directive:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT exec_date,
    100 * SUM(CASE WHEN cached = 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  / SUM(1) cached_no,
    100 * SUM(CASE WHEN cached != 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  / SUM(1) cached_yes FROM requests FORCE INDEX(`is_cached`) GROUP BY exec_date;
```

MySQL optimizer selects index which returns less rows to scan, in your case this counts are very close for both indexes (436695 vs 440493).